# How to deactivate playing a sound

Tags: swift, skaction, playsound

I have been trying to figure out how to deactivate playing a sound. I tried to attached a `removeAtionWithKey` with a sound action, and it seems to be working fine, but the sound does not stop to play. Is this because I am using action in `SpriteKit`?

If this problem is solved here instead of importing `AVFoundation`, then could you give me some examples to stop a sound from being played? Or, if importing `AVFoundation` is preferred in this case, could you provide me with some code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to use AVFoundation.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String) {

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "mp3")

    if (url == nil) {
        print("Could not find the file \(filename)")
    }

    do { backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil) } catch let error as NSError { print(error.debugDescription)}

    if backgroundMusicPlayer == nil {
        print("Could not create audio player")
    }

    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}

var Sound: AVAudioPlayer!

func playSound(filename: String) {

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "wav")

    if (url == nil) {
        print("Could not find the file \(filename)")
    }

    do { Sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url!, fileTypeHint: nil) } catch let error as NSError { print(error.debugDescription)}

    if Sound == nil {
        print("Could not create audio player")
    }

    Sound.prepareToPlay()
    Sound.play()
}
```

And here's what you want to achieve (if I understood well):

```
@IBAction func MusicButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if backgroundMusicPlayer.playing {
        backgroundMusicPlayer.stop()
    }
    else {
        playBackgroundMusic("SomeMusicName")
    }
}
```

Stopping the music with AVFoundation is as easy as `.stop()` ^^!

Comment: Thank!! but these code does not work well in my source code. In GameStartScene file, I set the sound. After transition to GameScene file and the screen is touched, I want to discard the sound. So, what I tried in my GameScene was that inside GameStartScene, 'var Sound: AVFoudation'. Iin GameScene, 'var gameStartScene: GameStartScene!' Inside the touch began, gameStartScene.Sound.stop(). It looked fine but code does not seem to accept my efforts.....Why is this an error??? I am unable to figure out how to handle this. It is very helpful if you could have some idea to this solution.